# CSS Checkbox/Toggle Spacing Issue

Tags: css

I am attempting to recreate an iPhone-like checkbox/toggle area. The result should look like this (notice the clean spacing between the toggle buttons)

[image: Toggle]

However, I'm encountering an issue with the spacing between the toggles/checkboxes. Instead of `.togglebox` being spaced with what looks like ~10px padding, they are lining up right under each other. I've tried `margin`, `padding`, `width`, `height`, etc. without any luck.

Here is my current coding: http://jsfiddle.net/eHnn5/1/

Comment: I know you've done a lot already, but maybe have a look at http://iphone.hohli.com/ - maybe you can find the answer in their framework

Comment: how about this - http://jsfiddle.net/eHnn5/2/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add height property in #toggleboxcategories as the child element is positioned absolute, there will be no use of padding or margin in this case.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you - this works as does @Zoltan Toth's answer. Thank you very much for the help.